# How to install pymssql module in Python 3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6, pymssql

I have been through a couple of documentations involving FreeTDS, Wheel, git and github but nothing was working on my Windows 10 PC with Python 3.6 but I need to install it. I'm working on a project and I'm most comfortable with mssql which is already installed in my pc.

Comment: Would you show us what you have tried so far, and any errors that you received?

Comment: I succesfully installed it from pre-built wheel at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pymssql

Answer (score 8):

this seems to work [from](http://pymssql.org/en/stable/freetds.html)

> export PYMSSQL_BUILD_WITH_BUNDLED_FREETDS=1
>
> pip install pymssql

Comment: Wheels for Python 3.6 github issue link at https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/473

Answer (score 1):

Remember to install `FreeTDS` first.

Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install freetds-dev
```

Mac OS X with Homebrew:

```
brew install freetds
```

Finally:

```
pip install pymssql
```

Answer (score 0):

As the site [pymssql_documentation page](https://pypi.org/project/pymssql/) states that the module is deprecated,

we can use `pip install "pymssql<3.0"`. It works on python 3.0 and above.

> I think they should change it in the main copy area as well. as of 12/17/2019 it is still showing `pip install pymssql`, which has been updated on Nov 16 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the newest build of pymssql from gitub:

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql
```

Also works for python2

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql
```

---

UPDATE:

For `macOS Big Sur Apple M1` chip processor:

- You will need to install Rosetta2 emulator for the new ARM silicon (M1 chip). I just installed Rosetta2 via terminal using:

```sh
/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
```

- Homebrew for ARM M1 chip:

```sh
arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

- Homebrew for M1 ARM command to install packages: `arch -x86_64 brew install <package>`. It is necessary to install [FreeTDS](http://packagehttp://www.freetds.org) before installing the `pymssql`.

```sh
arch -x86_64 brew install freetds
```

Finally:

```sh
pip install pymssql
```

output:

```sh
Collecting pymssql
  Using cached pymssql-2.1.5.tar.gz (167 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pymssql
  Building wheel for pymssql (PEP 517) ... done
  Created wheel for pymssql: filename=pymssql-2.1.5-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl size=287029 
.
.
.
Successfully built pymssql
Installing collected packages: pymssql
Successfully installed pymssql-2.1.5
```