# No module named pymssql after pip3 install pymssql

Tags: python, pymssql

I have kubernetes pod with image: debian:9.4. I do:

```
  apt -y install python3.6
  apt -y install python3-pip
  pip3 install pymssql
```

But when I run script

```
  import pymssql
  connection = pymssql.connect(server='', DATABASE='', user='', password='')
```

I get

```
Collecting pymssql
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1e/68/ecb6fdOee024a9ed8a852e7993ba0d059039a9cbc03a515bc1c8b92f8014/pymssg1-2.2.1.tar.gz 170kB) 
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info: 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<string>", line 1, in <module> 
File "irtmp/pip-build-hhjppxzp/pymssql/setup.py", line 54 
raise Exception(f"Unsupported environment value {env_name}={val}") 

SyntaxError: invalid syntax 

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-hhjppxzp/pymssql/ 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "db.py", line 1, in <module> 
import pymssql
ImportError: No module named 'pymssql'
```

I have tried install pymssql directly (without pip)

```
apt -y install python3-pymysql
```

but end is the same

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "db.py", line 1, in <module> 
import pymssql
ImportError: No module named 'pymssql'
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: try, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490286/how-to-install-pymssql-module-in-python-3-6

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try a miniconda version to install a environment and keep it there, it will it help to disguise what exactly is in the conda env.